# How can I remove the border around the current line in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I remove the horizontal line bounds on the selected line in VS Code? Illustration below:

[image]

I've searched through Google, and VS Code's editor settings though cannot find the toggle. The Color Theme used in 'Dark High Contract'.

Comment: try setting `editor.renderLineHighlight`

Comment: @rioV8. Thank you. Setting that to `none` in the GUI (I couldn't find the JSON file) solves the problem! Please feel free to post as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a result of using a high contrast theme. You can make the line highlight border transparent or whatever colour you wish by putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#0000" // #RGBA. can also #RRGGBBAA, #RGB, #RRGGBB
}
```

Or you could just nuke line highlighting altogether by putting `"editor.renderLineHighlight": "none",` in settings.json.